# How to set the size of browser using QtWebKit

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtwebkit

Recently I use PyQt4 to crawl some web pages. I want to set different size of the browser which is generated by `QWebView().show()`. I tried to use the following code snippet to set the size:

```
self.qsize = QWebPage().viewportSize()
self.qsize.setHeight(3000)
self.qsize.setWidth(1000)
print self.qsize.height()
print self.qsize.width()
```

But the browser displayed is always the same size.

Please give me some tips on how to set the size of the browser displayed by **QWebView**. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested this, the window resizes itself after loadFinished is emitted:

```
import sys 
from PySide.QtCore import QUrl, QSize
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebView


class Browser(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.web_view = QWebView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.web_view)

        self.web_view.loadFinished.connect(self._load_finished)

    def _load_finished(self):
        frame = self.web_view.page().mainFrame()
        self.web_view.page().setViewportSize(frame.contentsSize())
        self.resize(frame.contentsSize())
        html_data = frame.toHtml()


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    browser = Browser() 
    r = QUrl("http://www.yahoo.com")
    browser.web_view.load(r)
    browser.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks! It's the **resize** method to enlarge the size of browser. When I studied the use of **QWebView**, I had not studied the usage of **QWidget** that **QWebView** inherits from.